# add select type to fnadddata

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a datatable with lots of rows. I need to add a new row to the datatable (just client side, I want to use ajax to insert that new row in mysql). Most of the data I want to add in the columns are select-lists (which are retrived from mysql). My current add row function looks like this:

```
function fnAddRow() {       
var addData = {
    "sno": "<span id='txt'><img src='images/green_check.png' onClick='saveRow(this)';/><img src='images/red_cross.png' onClick='cancelEdit(this)';/></span>",       
    "project": "",
    "year": "<select name='year' id='year' ><option value='2012'>2012</option><option value='2013'>2013</option></select>",
};
oTable.fnAddData(addData); }
```

The data for 'project' should come from a mysql table. How do I add that? Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ajax to get your project data as well:

HTML:

```
<input id="AddButton" type="button" />
<table id="dataTable">
    ...
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fnGetProjectFromMySQL() {
    var projectHTML;
    $.ajax({
        url: "code/getMySQLData.php",
        success: function (mySqlData) {
            //Build your project html here using mySQLData
            projectHTML = "";
        }
    });
    return projectHTML;
}

function fnAddRow(oTable) {       
    var addData = {
        "sno": "<span id='txt'><img src='images/green_check.png' onClick='saveRow(this)';/><img src='images/red_cross.png' onClick='cancelEdit(this)';/></span>",       
        "project": fnGetProjectFromMySQL(),
        "year": "<select name='year' id='year' ><option value='2012'>2012</option><option value='2013'>2013</option></select>"
    };
    oTable.fnAddData(addData); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $("#dataTable").dataTable();

    $("#AddButton").click(function () {
        fnAddRow(oTable);
    });
});
```

I guess there are a few different ways to get this done. Google and javascript questions on stackoverflow should find you what you need:
[DataTables - How to add a row](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/add_row.html)

Comment: Thanks, this logic worked for me, thou its quite lengthy because I have 10 such columns, but there is no other way I guess??

Comment: @user1165952 Generally if I build a html element(such as a select), I end up piecing the code together manually.
If you are using some sort of framework, say MVC3 in .NET, or Yii for php they might have some functions where you can just put some data in, and they will automatically create the html object in, but that is a different question and depends on your framework. Otherwise you need to do it old school and build your html step by step.